# Only one checkbox is checked at the time

Tags: javascript, html

How to allow only one checkbox to be checked at the time in a form by clicking button submit using pure Javascript? I know I should use radio buttons, but I am required to do using checkboxes and I have no idea how.

Comment: What have  you tried?

Comment: Take a look at duplicated answer, it's pretty similar, should help you.